# React app, cannot find library, which I have installed manually

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yargs

I am building a React app. I installed yargs and argsert manually by npm. For some reason, when I start the development server, I get the following error and stack trace. The two modules in question are listed clearly as argsert and yargs. I am unsure of how to proceed. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

> webpack-dev-server --mode development

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/argsert'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/josh/devel/react-app/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:2:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

package.json

```
 {                                                                                                                                                                       
   "name": "react-app",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
   "build": "webpack --mode production",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
   "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
   "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
   "webpack": "^4.42.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
   },
   "dependencies": {
   "argsert": "^1.0.9",
   "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
   "react": "^16.13.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
   "weak-key": "^1.0.1",
   "yargs": "^15.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: By manually installed by npm you mean you ran command `npm i argsert yargs` and they successfully installed?

Comment: Could you post the part of the code that uses the libraries?

Comment: @Drew, yes I successfully installed the packages by npm.

Comment: @Juho, the code that uses the library argsert is located in the yargs package.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm i argsert yargs` if it is not working working try to `npm install` if even tough it is not working. Delete argsert and yargs from `package.json` and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed node and npm from source and that seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You should mark this answer then as the accepted answer. It might help others searching for similar issues to find resolved solutions. Also consider contributing by adding hints how to do the thing you did.